# rendering different view engine in zend depending on extension

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a normal phtml template and another one in HAML. So somewhere in my Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initView()   
{
     $view = new Haml_View();
     $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
     $viewRenderer->setView($view);
     Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
     return $view    
}
```

I initialize to use my Haml_View, but what i want is if the script filename has an extension .haml, it'll use Haml_view if not, then it'll use the regular Zend_view.

So i guess my question is, is there any way to find out what the current view script filename will be use?

Thanks

Comment: Don't refer to Zend Framework as "Zend" especially when you use "Engine" in the title. Zend Engine and Zend Framework MVC View instances are nothing to do with each other.

Comment: what? clarify as i don't see my mistake. zend has mvc component yes? zend view is the engine that renders the view templates yes? i do not meant to interchange them - if that was your impression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The basic workflow of a ZF MVC request is as follows:
>
> 1. Application bootstrapping
> 2. Routing
> 3. Dispatch
>
> Zend_Application takes care of only the first item in that list,
>   bootstrapping. At that time, we have no idea what the request actually
>   is -- that happens during routing. It's only after we have routed that
>   we know what module, controller, and action were requested.

Source: http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts.html

So you can't switch the view class based on script suffix in the bootstrap because the routing has not occured yet. You could do it in a FrontController plugin as early as [routeShutdown](http://nethands.de/download/zenddispatch_en.pdf), but I feel it's more natural to do it in an Action Helper. The normal methods to figure out the view script path are in Zend_View and Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer. Both of these are easily available in an Action Helper.

Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer is also an Action Helper and it needs to init before, so let's do our switch after the init, in the preDisptatch call of an Action Helper.

First, you need to register your helper. A good place is in the bootstrap with your view:

```
protected function _initView()
{
    $view = new Haml_View();
    $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
    return $view;
}


protected function _initHelpers()
{
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
        new Haml_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewFallback()
    );
}
```

And the helper would look like this:

```
class Haml_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewFallback extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {

        /** @var $viewRenderer Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer */
        $viewRenderer = $this->getActionController()->getHelper('ViewRenderer');
        /** @var $view Haml_View */
        $view = $viewRenderer->view;

        /**
         * what i want is if the script filename has an extension .haml,
         * it'll use Haml_view if not, then it'll use the regular Zend_view
         */
        $viewRenderer->setViewSuffix('haml');
        $script = $viewRenderer->getViewScript();
        if (!$view->getScriptPath($script)) {
            $viewRenderer->setView(new Zend_View());
            $viewRenderer->setViewSuffix('phtml');
            $viewRenderer->init();
        }

    }
}
```

If there is no file with the haml extension in the default path, we assume there is one with phtml extension, and we modifiy the ViewRenderer accordingly. Don't forget to init the ViewRenderer again.

Comment: Chris, thanks, you understood what i need. we're almost there. the problem here is, if i have index.haml.phtml, zend will produce an error, saying that it could not find index.phtml. we should not set the view suffix, then it defeats the purpose of discovering if the view script available is a .haml.phtml or .phtml only. if i don't make sense, please let me know.

Comment: so perhaps the question here is now - is there a way so that zend will try to look for .haml.phtml or .phtml automatically?

Comment: oops my apologies - this solution is PERFECT! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:-

```
if(!file_exists('path/to/view.haml'){
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
}
```

May work, although I haven't tested it.

**Edit:**

You could try this in your controller:-

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() 
    {
        $paths = $this->view->getScriptPaths();
        $path = $paths[0];
        $script = $path . $this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->getViewScript();
        if(!file_exists($script)){
            $this->viewSuffix = 'hmal';
        }
    }

    public function indexAction() 
    {

    }
}
```

I'm not 100% happy with the `$path = $paths[0]` bit, but I don't have time to look into it any further. Hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for trying to help - but that is my problem how do i get 'path/to/view.haml' in bootstrap.php?

Comment: Put into init() in your controller?

Comment: hey guys thanks for trying to help - but i need to set the view renderer. I have different view renderer when its a HAML temlate, and i want it to use a default one if its using the default Zend template.